# Flex - Localization and Resource Modules - Runtime errors

Tags: apache-flex, localization, module, flex4, resourcebundle

I've created an application that includes a number of Modules and uses Parsley framework.
Ant is used to build the application.
Recently I thought of using Resource Bundles and implemented it in the system by creating a locale/en_US folder under the src. I added a portal.properties file with all my strings defined.

In my modules, I added the metadata

```
<fx:Metadata>
    [ResourceBundle("portal")]
</fx:Metadata>
```

In the ant build file, I added the below lines within mxmlc.

```
<locale>@{locale}</locale>
<source-path path-element="${myapp.flex.app.locale}/{locale}"/>
<include-resource-bundles>portal</include-resource-bundles>
```

The build works fine and when I deploy the application and open it in my browser, I'm greeted with many errors thrown by the Flash player.
But if I dismiss the messages, its working fine. My strings are replaced with the values in the property file, but how do I stop the runtime errors being thrown up?

I get the below error.

```
Error: Unable to load resource module from portal
at MethodInfo-637()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at ModuleInfoProxy/moduleEventHandler()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at ModuleInfoProxy/moduleEventHandler()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at ModuleInfo/errorHandler()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your resource modules are loaded from the domain that is different from the domain of main SWF file , then you may want to read this http://blog.mediarain.com/2009/08/flex-loading-remote-modules-throws-the-following-error-unable-to-load-resource-module-from/

Comment: Are you using the same Flex SDK to build your resource bundles and main SWF files?

Comment: Using the same sdk only, and the resources are not converted to swf files, used as property files only.

Answer (score 0):

Do you include into your ant build the following

```
<keep-as3-metadata>ResourceBundle</keep-as3-metadata>
```

?